# Filtros em datables só funcionando 1 vez

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-datatables

Bom dia galera do stack overflow.
Eu estou com um problema há algum tempo, onde não consigo entender o seu motivo.

Estou trabalhando com datatables do php, onde eu faço alguns filtros personalizados.
Quando eu seleciono por exemplo, 2 checkbox, e clico no botão ele funciona perfeitamente, logo após, se eu tentar mudar esse filtro, desmarcando essa caixa e selecionando outra, ela não filtra, mas envia a requisição normalmente.

Segue alguns códigos da requisição

```
$("#btnFiltrar").on('click',function() {
        if($(".chkTipoEducacional").is(':checked')) {
            var i =$('.chkTipoEducacional').attr('data-columns');
            var v =$('.chkTipoEducacional').val();
            dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
            console.log(v);
        }
    });
    $("#btnFiltrar").on('click',function() {
        if($(".chkTipoComercial").is(':checked')) {
            var i =$('.chkTipoComercial').attr('data-columns');
            var v =$('.chkTipoComercial').val();
            dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
            console.log(v);

        }
    });
    $("#btnFiltrar").on('click',function() {
        if($(".chkTipoProfissional").is(':checked')) {
            var i =$('.chkTipoProfissional').attr('data-columns');
            var v =$('.chkTipoProfissional').val();
            dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
            console.log(v);
        }
    });
```

E alguns exemplos do php

```
if(!empty($requestData['columns'][8]['search']['value']) && !empty($requestData['columns'][11]['search']['value']) && !empty($requestData['columns'][12]['search']['value'])){
    $sql .= " AND issued_date BETWEEN '".$requestData['columns'][11]['search']['value']."' AND '".$requestData['columns'][12]['search']['value']."'";
}

if(!empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value'])){
    $sql.=" AND licensed_version LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Tente mudar attr por prop

Comment: Quando eu coloco o prop, ele busca todos os filtros, não apenas o selecionado.

Comment: "SELECT razao_social,organization_name, organization_type,edition, licensed_version,issued_date,updates_expiry_date,support_expiry_date,advanced_clients_licensed,users_licensed,id_license   FROM license_view WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( users_licensed < '2017-02-05' OR  users_licensed > '2017-02-05' )  AND licensed_version LIKE '2017-02-05%'  AND organization_type LIKE  '2017-02-05%' OR\torganization_type LIKE  '2017-02-05%' AND  edition LIKE '2017-02-05%'  OR  edition LIKE '2017-02-05%' ORDER BY razao_social   asc   LIMIT 0 ,10   "

O Sql dele vem assim.